# Read tcp packets from cap file one by one?

Tags: linux, sockets, wireshark, tcpdump

It's possible to read packet one by one from a file?
  I want to split my cap file in such a condition depend on the contents of packets, such as when I capture a long term packets stream, and I just need some packets to abstract, for example, I just want to abstract a tr069 session, from do a rpc calling to the end of response, then redirect these packets to a file, of course, they can mix many other packets, that's no problem, I just need these packets during the seesion, then I keep the resulted file as my record, so how can do it?
  tcpdump or tshark or any other unix utils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe filters of tcpdump solves your problem.
You can read your cap file by using tcpdump and output filtered result directly to file.
Example:

```
tcpdump -r big.pcap -w small.pcap "src port 2438"
```

See man page of [pcap-filter(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter) for more about filters.